# Parking lot ticket probability.

Tags: probability

I am struggling to find a quick an intuitive solution to this problem:
You parked your car on Monday and didn't pay for parking. You leave your car there until the end of Tuesday. You know that you have the same probability of getting a ticket on Monday and Tuesday. You also know that if you get a ticket on Monday, then you won't get one on Tuesday. At the same time, you know that the probability of getting a ticket on either of the two days is 0.84. What is the probability that you get a fine on Monday?

I have solved it this way:
Let's condition everything with time. We know that

- P(getting ticket on Monday | it is Monday today) = P(ticket on Tuesday | it is tuesday today).

At this point, we can think that the probability of getting a ticket on either of the two days is observed on Monday, so that P(M or T| it is Monday) =  0.84. Now I have made an assumption, but I still struggle to properly motivate it.
We have that

- P(M or T| it is Monday)=P(M| it's M) + P(T and not M| it's T).

Now we can derive the second component:

- P(M or T| it's M) = P(not M| it's M)*P(T| it's T)
- I have doubts about this step as well.
  Now we simply get that 0.84 = p + (1-p)p, or 0.16 = 1-p-(1-p)p. From the latter, we get that p=0.6.

I would like to understand a more intuitive and sensible way of solving this problem.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the probability you get a ticket on any day be $x$

Now,  there is a chance you get a ticket on Monday and if not there is again an equal chance you get a ticket on Tuesday. The total probability you even get a ticket is given as $0.84$.

$$P(getting\ a\ ticket) = P(Ticket\ on\ Monday) + P(No\ ticket\ on\ Monday) \cdot P(Ticket\ on\ Tuesday)$$
$$\Rightarrow 0.84 = x + (1-x) \cdot x$$

Solving the quadratic gives us $0.6$.

So, the probability of a fine on Monday is $0.6$